# UICollectionView reloadData only works one time in two

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, pdfkit

I have a `UIViewController` that presents a `UIDocumentPicker` to pick PDF files, and contains a `UICollectionView` that displays them (each cell contains a `PDFView` to do so).

Here is the code:

```
import MobileCoreServices; import PDFKit; import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var urls: [URL] = []
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    @IBAction func pickFile() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [kUTTypePDF as String], in: .import)
            documentPicker.delegate = self
            documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
            self.present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: PDFCollectionViewCell.identifier, bundle: .main),
                                forCellWithReuseIdentifier: PDFCollectionViewCell.identifier)
    }
    
    init() { super.init(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: .main) }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) { fatalError() }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: PDFCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! PDFCollectionViewCell
        cell.pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: urls[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return urls.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
    // MARK: PDF Picker Delegate
    func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
    
    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.urls.append(contentsOf: urls)
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }
}

class PDFCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    static let identifier = "PDFCollectionViewCell"
    
    @IBOutlet weak var pdfView: PDFView! { didSet { setPdfViewUI() } }
    
    func setPdfViewUI() {
        pdfView.displayMode = .singlePage
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        pdfView.displayDirection = .vertical
        pdfView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Now, for some reason, the `collectionView.reloadData()` actually only works one time in two. It works the first time, then the second time nothing happens, then the third time the collection view is updated again with the three expected elements...

I realized that even if I'm calling `reloadData()`, the dataSource and delegate methods (`numberOfItems`/`cellForItem`) are not getting called when this happens.

Any idea of what is happening?

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: I can ensure that I don't have any other code in `viewDidLoad`/`appear` methods, that the `pickFile` function is actually called fine and that the url is correctly fetched, with the `urls` array being updated as it should before calling `reloadData()`.

Also, I have tried this with both `UITableView` and `UICollectionView`, and I'm having this issue in each situation. It just feels like something is wrong either with the fact that I'm using a `PDFView`, or with the document picker.

Comment: Do you have anything else in `viewWillAppear()` / `viewDidAppear()` that's not visible here in the question?

Comment: Hi @TarunTyagi, absolutely not, I've pasted the whole code (apart from the XIB files, btw)

Comment: Have you ensured that the `reloadData` inside of you async block is getting called when you expect it to? Maybe also make sure that the `urls` array that you're appending is non-empty. Also, I'm not seeing what calls `pickFile`, I'm wondering if maybe there's some deallocation issue with `pickFile`'s `documentPicker` since it's created inside that dispatch block?

Comment: @WongWray Thank you for your comment. I ensured everything you said, I've even created a `TestCollectionView` subclass that overrides `UICollectionView` and its function `reloadData()` to log the fact that I actually enter this method, and that's what happens. And I've also checked that `urls` is not empty, and that `pickFile` executes fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very very weird bug that happens when you use `PDFView` in the `UICollectionViewCell`. I confirmed this in following environment -

1. Xcode 12.5
2. iPhone SE 2020 (iOS 14.6)

`UICollectionView.reloadData()` calls are **not reliably working** when `PDFView` is added as a subview inside `UICollectionViewCell.contentView`.

##### What else can we try?

Surprisingly `UICollectionView.insertItems(at:)` works where `UICollectionView.reloadData()` doesn't for this case. There's working code sample provided at the end of this answer for anyone else trying to reproduce/confirm the issue.

##### Why this might be happening?

Honestly no idea. `UICollectionView.reloadData()` is supposed to guarantee that UI is in sync with your dataSource. Let's look at the stack traces of `reloadData()` (when it works in this case) & `insertItems(at:)`.

###### ReloadData_StackTrace

[image]

###### InsertItemsAtIndexPaths_StackTrace

[image]

##### Conclusion

1. `reloadData()` relies on `layoutSubviews()` to perform the UI refresh. This is inherited from `UIView` like - `UIView.layoutSubviews() > UIScrollView > UICollectionView`. It's a very well known UI event and can easily be intercepted by any subclass of `UIView`. `PDFView: UIView` can also do that. **Why does it happen inconsistently?** Only someone who can disassemble & inspect the `PDFKit.framework` may know about this. This is clearly a bug in `PDFView.layoutSubviews()` implementation that interferes with it's superview's `layoutSubviews()` implementation.
2. `insertItems(at:)` adds new instance(s) of cell(s) at specified indexPath(s) and clearly does not rely on `layoutSubviews()` and hence works reliably in this case.

##### Sample Code

```
import MobileCoreServices
import PDFKit
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // MARK: - Instance Variables
    private lazy var flowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = {
        let sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20, right: 20)
        
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        layout.sectionInset = sectionInset
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 20
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 20
        
        return layout
    }()
    
    private lazy var pdfsCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
        cv.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        cv.backgroundColor = .red
        
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.delegate = self
        return cv
    }()
    
    private lazy var pickFileButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 300, y: 610, width: 60, height: 40)) // hard-coded for iPhone SE
        button.setTitle("Pick", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .purple
        
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pickFile), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    
    private var urls: [URL] = []
    
    
    // MARK: - View Life Cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.view.addSubview(pdfsCollectionView)
        pdfsCollectionView.register(
            PDFCollectionViewCell.self,
            forCellWithReuseIdentifier: PDFCollectionViewCell.cellIdentifier
        )
        
        self.view.addSubview(pickFileButton)
    }
    
    
    // MARK: - Helpers
    @objc private func pickFile() {
        let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [kUTTypePDF as String], in: .import)
        documentPicker.delegate = self
        documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
        self.present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: PDFCollectionViewCell.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PDFCollectionViewCell
        cell.pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: urls[indexPath.row])
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return urls.count
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
    func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        
        // CAUTION:
        // These urls are in the temporary directory - `.../tmp/<CFBundleIdentifier>-Inbox/<File_Name>.pdf`
        // You should move/copy these files to your app's document directory
        
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let count = self.urls.count
                var indexPaths: [IndexPath] = []
                for i in 0..<urls.count {
                    indexPaths.append(IndexPath(item: count+i, section: 0))
                }
                
                self.urls.append(contentsOf: urls)
                
                // Does not work reliably
                /*
                self.pdfsCollectionView.reloadData()
                */
                
                // Works reliably
                self.pdfsCollectionView.insertItems(at: indexPaths)
            }
        })
    }
}


class PDFCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    static let cellIdentifier = "PDFCollectionViewCell"
    
    lazy var pdfView: PDFView = {
        let view = PDFView(frame: self.contentView.bounds)
        view.displayMode = .singlePage
        view.autoScales = true
        view.displayDirection = .vertical
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        
        self.contentView.addSubview(view)
        view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        view.backgroundColor = .yellow
        
        return view
    }()
}
```

Comment: Fantastic investigation! After I reproduced the issue I was going to try inserting instead but never got round to it for some reason

Comment: Hi @TarunTyagi and thanks a lot for your awesome investigation. Good to know there is still a way to do it with PDFKit. Thanks also for your advice about copying the files into a safer place, would `.documentsDirectory` be OK for that?

Comment: Yes, `.documentsDirectory` should be fine.

Comment: In case this solves your issue, please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is being caused by the PDFViews in your cells, for reasons I'm not sure about. PDFView may be too heavyweight for use in a collection view cell, or it may have some issue when reloading or re-adding a document. I reproduced your issue without managing to fix it, though you may want to bear these points in mind:

- You're using a deprecated initalizer for the document picker
- The "inbox" url you're given is not guaranteed to be persistent, indeed you can see files appearing and disappearing in there as you select more documents, so you probably want to look into moving selected files into a more permanent home

Addressing these things made no difference to the strange reloading issue. What I did instead was `import QuickLookThumbnailing`, add an image view to the cell instead of a PDF view, and add this code:

```
class PDFCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    static let identifier = "PDFCollectionViewCell"
    
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    private var request: QLThumbnailGenerator.Request?
        
    func load(_ url: URL) {
        let req = QLThumbnailGenerator.Request.init(fileAt: url, size: bounds.size, scale: UIScreen.main.scale, representationTypes: .all)
        
        QLThumbnailGenerator.shared.generateRepresentations(for: req) {
            [weak self]
            rep, type, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.imageView.image = rep?.uiImage
            }
        }
        request = req
    }
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        if let request = request {
            QLThumbnailGenerator.shared.cancel(request)
            self.request = nil
        }
        imageView.image = nil
    }
}
```

This asynchronously renders thumbnails for whatever URL you pass it, increasing the quality as it goes.

Comment: Thank you very much! As I am also using a cell with an image view to achieve the same result in my project but with a UIImage, I'll use this solution which is very convenient. Simple question, when would you call the `load(_ url: URL)` cell method?

Comment: When configuring the cell in cellForItemAt

Answer (score 0):

Somehow collectionView caches for milliseconds `reloadingData` so it wont reload twice as you call `reloadData()` twice,  also based on [apple developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618078-reloaddata):

> You should not call this method in the middle of animation blocks where items are being inserted or deleted. Insertions and deletions automatically cause the collection’s data to be updated appropriately.

I have some workaround to achieve this:

##### Invalidate collectionView layout:

As far as I know there is remove cache method inside `collectionViewLayout prepare`

```swift
collectionView!.reloadData()
collectionView!.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
collectionView!.layoutSubviews()
```